# 554 5.7.1 Relay access denied postfix

Tags: postfix, cyberpanel

I have facing problem with send email from cyberpanel rainloop. i'm testing on mx toolbox, its show

```
Status Ok   SMTP Reverse DNS Mismatch   OK - 170.64.156.12 resolves to mail.kacktus.com.au
Status Ok   SMTP Valid Hostname OK - Reverse DNS is a valid Hostname
Status Ok   SMTP Banner Check   OK - Reverse DNS matches SMTP Banner
Status Ok   SMTP TLS    OK - Supports TLS.
Status Ok   SMTP Connection Time    1.123 seconds - Good on Connection time
Status Ok   SMTP Open Relay OK - Not an open relay.
Status Ok   SMTP Transaction Time   2.368 seconds - Good on Transaction Time

Connecting to 170.64.156.12

220 mail.kacktus.com.au ESMTP Postfix [869 ms]
EHLO keeper-us-east-1d.mxtoolbox.com
250-mail.kacktus.com.au
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 30720000
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250-DSN
250 CHUNKING [337 ms]
MAIL FROM:<supertool@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com>
250 2.1.0 Ok [340 ms]
RCPT TO:<test@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com>
554 5.7.1 <test@mxtoolboxsmtpdiag.com>: Relay access denied [340 ms]
```

**This is postfix config:**

```
myhostname = mail.kacktus.com.au
mynetworks = 170.64.156.12, 127.0.0.0/8
message_size_limit = 30720000
virtual_alias_domains =
virtual_alias_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_forwardings.cf, mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_email2email.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = proxy:mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql-virtual_mailboxes.cf
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_use_tls = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
virtual_create_maildirsize = yes
virtual_maildir_extended = yes
proxy_read_maps = $local_recipient_maps $mydestination $virtual_alias_maps $virtual_alias_domains $virtual_mailbox_maps $virtual_mailbox_domains $relay_recipient_maps $relay_domains $canonical_maps $sender_cano>
virtual_transport = dovecot
dovecot_destination_recipient_limit = 1
inet_interfaces = all
smtp_tls_security_level = may
disable_vrfy_command = yes
smtpd_milters = inet:127.0.0.1:8891
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
milter_default_action = accept

tls_server_sni_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmail_ssl.map
```

I'm trying long time to find solutions, Can't figure out. im using digitalocean droplet with cyberpanel.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is exactly saying why it is not working. The MX Toolbox is trying to use your server as a relay and your server is not allowing relaying.

If you want to be an open relay (**which you should not want**), you can add `0.0.0.0/0` to your `mynetworks`, but for testing purposes from MX Toolbox you can set it temporarily.

Some time ago I made a simple Ansible role to configure a Postfix server, you might useful information there: https://github.com/polatsinan/postfix_server

Especially look for the `templates/main.cf.j2` file.

Comment: i'm add 0.0.0.0/0 to mynetworks, mx tool shown Ok . but, email not send from cyberpanel rainloop. how to find bug/solution.

Comment: You should add `0.0.0.0/0` only temporarily for testing, otherwise you will be an open relay. You should check your mail logs, usually `/var/log/mail.log`, `/var/log/maillog` or `/var/log/postfix.log`.